# Should I be worried about this patch under my dog’s chin?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition, veterinarian

As my dog was lying next to me, I noticed a small patch that appears to be bald and possibly raw right under her mouth. It’s a couple centimeters across and a little bit red. Any idea what this is and if it should be a cause for concern? I am a new dog owner and don’t want to be taking her to the vet for every little thing but also obviously don’t want to delay if it is something that should be looked at.[image: red patch on dog]

Comment: I'd say vet is not an unreasonable next step